# CSS class overwrites other

Tags: html, css, overwrite

I have HTML tables where the following CSS is applied:

```
.tbst th,
td {
    padding: 12px 3px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
}
```

and

```
.cmstb th,
td {
    padding: 12px 3px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
}
```

One table is using `.tbst` class, the other one `.cmstb`. But from some reason, the second CSS is applied to both tables, so the second CSS overwrite the style in first CSS. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The answers for your question is override with same answer by these guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are styling the `th` correctly, but for `td`, the style is oerwritten, because it is not specific to any table. make it specific to those tables

```
.tbst th,
 .tbst td {
    padding: 12px 3px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
}
and

.cmstb th,
.cmstb td {
    padding: 12px 3px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

td class is being overidden. Also they are both using all the same values except for font-size. you should condense it using less. and then you would only apply the difference to the second table.

> ```
> .tbst th, .tbst td {
> padding: 12px 3px !important;
> text-align: center !important;
> vertical-align: middle !important;
> border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
> font-size: 12px;
> overflow: hidden !important;
> line-height: 24px !important; }
> ```

and

> ```
> .cmstb th, .cmstb td { 
> font-size: 14px; }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting td twice, the last defined properties will always override those previously defined.

Even nicer (and more performant) CSS would be the following:

```
.cmstb-th,
.cmstb-td,
.tbst-th,
.tbst-td {
  padding: 12px 3px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}

.tbst-th,
.tbst-td {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cmstb-th,
.cmstb-td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Why the overuse of !important by the way? Mostly this means you have (another) inheritance issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ad question - overwriting default table style used in template.